# ajax and jsonp getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

okay so i have a ajax script calling a RESTful url, and this is what it's returning to me, some json like so

```
{
"name": "camera-livingroom",
"address": 0,
"addressStr": "unknown",
"classID": 0,
"devProtocol": 999,
"displayInUI": true,
"displayLongState": "disconnected",
"displayRawState": "disconnected",
"folderID": 476125486,
"hasStateToDisplay": true,
"id": 1241016235,
"lastChanged": 479347270,
"lastChangedDateStr": "2015-03-11",
"lastChangedRFC3339": "2015-03-10T22:01:10Z",
"lastChangedRFC822": "Tue, 10 Mar 2015 22:01:10 GMT",
"lastChangedTimeStr": "12:01:10 AM",
"type": "Camera",
"typeFlags": 0,
"typeSupportsDim": false,
"typeSupportsEnergyMeter": false,
"typeSupportsHVAC": false,
"typeSupportsIO": false,
"typeSupportsOnOff": false,
"typeSupportsSensorValue": false,
"typeSupportsSpeedControl": false,
"typeSupportsSprinkler": false,
"versByte": 0,
"restParent": "devices"
}
```

This JSON i have no control over, and can't change because it's coming from a api on a program.

I'm calling the JSON with

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function load(Test) {


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                // TO DO
                url:  'http://SERVERIP:8176/devices/camera-livingroom.json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

        }

    </script>

    <a class="editLink" onclick="load('Test');">test af link</a>
```

But this is just returning "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error."

So what have i done wrong, and what do i do to fix it.

Comment: can you give the exact spot of the error, can't find any error in given code

Comment: Try using [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: It's when you click the button, the browser returns the error in the console

Comment: @Sima that just return this error to me.

Origin http://SERVERIP is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Ok your server doesn't allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin from a client. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) post, it may help you

Comment: But i dont have control of the header of the responding sever

Comment: Ok so when you are using $.ajax method show us the response of your ajax request in your browser.

Comment: That as i wrote the SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error."

Comment: And before try using 'json' as datatype not 'jsonp'

Comment: That Will return the access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I mean when you go to your browser console you also have a 'Network' tab. Use it to show the server response you should have an http return code and so other informations

Comment: status code 200
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT
Content-Length: 807
Content-Type: text/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 00:02:09 GMT
Server: IndigoWebServer/5.0

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just fine for me, so I did try using `$.getJSON`, same working result :

```
$.getJSON( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/contribute.json/master/schema.json?callback=?", function( data ){
  console.log( data );
});
```